# Msolservice - copy value from one attribute to another

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a large number of users in Azure where I need to copy the value in the attribute Office to the attribute State. If State contains a value and Office doesn't, State must be cleared. The two attributes must be the exact same afterwards. I have to use Powershell and MSonline/msolservice https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0

Any suggestions?

Comment: Write some code would be my suggestion. This site doesn't write some for you, and it does not walk you through writing it, perform your research for you, or supply you with links so that you don't have to make the required effort at performing your own tasks. Please, as you're not a brand new member here, read [ask], and its linked pages, to remind yourself of the site guidelines before asking any more incomplete or off topic questions.

Comment: `Get-MsolUser` and `Set-MsolUser` and some basic logic should do the trick. If you need more specific help you'll need to post your code.

Comment: Thank you, @Compo, for reminding me how it felt like when I first stuck my freshman head out on the internet and dared to ask a question of one my betters.

Comment: @PMental, you're of course right and I should have mentioned that I've spent a few hours trying to get this to work, and of course added a few of my failed efforts. Lesson learned.

Comment: Please use the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65907117/edit) to add them, complete with sufficient supporting information for us to reproduce the specific issue it is exhibiting, and perhaps your question can be progressed as on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clarified the logic.

What you need to do is to poll all users and check the two properties of `Office` and `State`.

A simple sample for your reference:

```
$users = Get-MsolUser

foreach($user in $users){
    if ($user.Office -ne $null -and $user.Office -ne $user.State) {
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -State $user.Office
    }
    if ($user.Office -eq $null -and $user.State -ne $null){
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -State "$null"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small comment, it's good practice to keep $null on the left for comparisons, as you can get confusing results in certain situations otherwise when collections/multiple values are involved. Not really the case here, but good practice to just do it as a habit.

Comment: D'oh! That did it. My fault was the second line, I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to clear the right set of users. Your solution is elegant and simple. Thank you!